# UTF8 Decoding Chinese Characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, character-encoding

I am using node.js and express to build an API which transforms chinese characters into their phonetic spelling (Pinyin) but I am having some utf8 decoding/encoding issues. My PHP Curl request to this API encodes the characters like this:

```
你好 (nǐ​hǎo) => ä½ å¥½
```

...so I have to decode them in my node application. I am using the following function:

```
function decode_utf8(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

and it works perfectly fine in most cases. However, I noticed some weird behavior. Here are two inputs, the value after `escape()` and the value after `decodeURIComponent()`:

```
你好 (nǐ​hǎo): ä½ å¥½ => %E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD => 你好
你 (nǐ​): ä½ => %E4%BD => URIError: URI malformed
```

The first one (nǐ​hǎo) works, but when only using the first of the two characters (nǐ​) it gives me an URIError? How is this possible? The input to the `decodeURIComponent()` function is the exact same for the nǐ​-part but it only works when combining it with another character. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're trying to decode doesn't resolve to valid utf8. Something is wrong with your PHP Curl request because it's not encoding `你 (nǐ​)` correctly. The percent encoded value should be `你 => %E4%BD%A0`